High resistance hookup wire
Does specifically high resistance wire exist from any manufacturer? I am looking at a potential solution to safety in high-voltage sense systems. The sensing circuit is very high impedance, but having long, delicate, low resistance sense wires carrying full voltage presents a system risk. Ideally, there would be a dedicated resistor at the source, but for manufacturing, this would be impossible.
Is there perhaps carbon impregnated wire designed for this purpose, something like old spark plug leads?

Why would manufacturing that be "impossible"?

Considering the low cost of current limiting resistors and standard hookup or stranded wire, why would you want expensive 50kohm/m cable with thick insulation?

XY problem. Instead of asking how to solve the problem of safely sensing the high voltage you've decided on a solution and then asked if it exists.

define "full voltage" and the number and length of wires with hookup purpose.

And what would be the problem with using high-resistance spark-plug wires? What are resistance and voltage requirements? Also, consider avoiding direct electrical connection, e.g., use photocoupler and fiber optic cable for connection.

Some ignition cables for cars are of “high resistance “ type, but we’re talking kohm here. Not enough for safety.

@JCollins What is your resistance per cm?

10k/cm would be reasonable I think

@GodJihyo it's a fair point. Presently I see no production solutions to the problem I'm looking at, so on that basis and supposing it isn't readily possible. If there is an existing solution in some form of production I'd love to know what it was

@JCollins It's impossible to give you a good solution when you haven't given us enough information to go on. We don't know anything about the sensing circuit, the voltages involved, the distance, the environment it's to be used in or how it's to be used. In short, you've told us almost nothing about the actual problem. The best I can tell you is you're best off having the HV protection right at the HV point, not distributed through the wires.

The question has yielded exactly the answers I've been looking for, I'm more confident to comment that it's a bit ridiculous to need to know the backstory of the question for it to be relevant. If I'm shopping for underwear, I don't show the staff my genitals.

Yes there is. It's used in cables that heat water pipes so they don't freeze in the winter. Like this: https://www.amazon.com/Flexible-Insulation-Resistant-Conditioning-Compressor/dp/B0CFD68DS9
Here is some plain insulated wire: https://www.a-msystems.com/p-784-formvar-insulated-nichrome-wire.aspx
You can find more with this search: https://www.bing.com/search?q=insulated+nichrome+wire

Nichrome wire isn't going to have anywhere near enough resistance for what the OP is asking. Even in very small gauges it's only hundreds of ohms per foot while they're asking for 10k/cm.

To be fair I added that comment on resistance after the answer was posted, so it's reasonable.
